# Background Foreground Signal Termination

Tags: c, shell

I have to write a shell that able to "print message about signal terminated the process" if a command is terminated by signal.

Example

```
> sleep 5
^C terminated by signal 2

> sleep 10 &
background pid is 4422
..... // after several lines
background pid is done: exit value 0

> sleep 11 &
background pid is 4442
> kill -15 4442
background pid is done: terminate by signal 15
```

However, in my code:

1) If I `^C` in `sleep 5,` it directly quit from the shell instead of terminate only the sleep process.

2) If I type `sleep 10 &`, it directly prints `background pid is 4422: exit value 0`. Thus, I think no sleep happening here and I couldn't perform the `kill -15 <process id>` too.

My best guess that it has something to do with my `launch` function (advice from a lot of people to use this function to **launch a program and wait for it to terminate**) and here is how it looks:

**notes:** I have a global variable called `runBg`, which actually I created just for a   tester if a background process exist then I set `runBg` to 1. However, I don't know whether this is a good idea or not.

```
int launch(char **args) {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int exitStat = 0;

    pid = fork(); 

    if (pid == 0) { 
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) { 
            printf("error1"); // debugging purposes
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) { 
        printf("error2"); // debugging purposes
    } else {
        do {
            if (runBg == 0) {
                waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
            } else if (runBg== 1) { 
                waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
            }
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status)); 
    }

    if (runBg== 1) {
        printf("Background PID: %d is done: exit value: %d", pid, exitStat);
    }

    if (status != 0 || WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        exitStat = 1;
    }

    return exitStat;
```

I tried to perform several test and it all seems to fall directly into `error1`.

Is it true that the first if condition `execvp ......` is the trouble maker?

It also seems that the `sleep 15 &` doesn't work because it doesn't go to the last `if statement` after the do-while loop right?

Looking forward to any of you helps. Let me know if I missed chuck of information in this thread as well. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect `waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);` is part of your problem.  Try narrowing it to an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jason is it because I used WUNTRACED? I suspect that too, but is it also possible because I don't give if (pid == -1) condition too?

Comment: Anybody could give suggestion?